# Solr "min" and "max" functions return only two decimal numbers

Tags: solr, max, min

**Solr** "min" function returns only two decimal numbers.

For example : I have multi prices **1.0012**, **2.7865**, **5.3456**.

When I use min and max functions in the solr query, the function returns minimum value as 1 and maximum value as **5.34**.

But I need **1.0012** and **5.3456** as minimum and maximum values.

I am trying to find a solution since a long time, still not finding any relative answer.

Comment: Can you post your SOLR schema.xml file here please?
We'd need to see what you have in the field type bits. Something along the following lines:
<fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>